# Docker port binding using gitlab-ci with gitlab-runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've noticed a problem, when configuring my gitlab-ci and gitlab-runner.

I want to have few separate application environments on one server, running on other external ports, but using same docker image.

### What I want to achieve

- `deploy-dev` running Apache at port `80` in container, but at external port `81`
- `deploy-rc`running Apache at port `80` in container, but on external port `82`

I've seen that `docker run` has `--publish` argument, that allows port binding, like `80:81`, but unfortunately I can't find any option in `gitlab-ci.yml` or gitlab-runner's `config.toml` to set that argument.

Is there any way to achieve port binding in Docker ran by gitlab-runner?

My `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
before_script:
# Install dependencies
- bash ci/docker_install.sh > /dev/null

deploy:
  image: webdevops/php-apache:centos-7-php56
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - dockertest
  script:
    - composer self-update
    - export SYMFONY_ENV=dev
    - composer install
    - app/console doc:sch:up --force
    - app/console doc:fix:load -e=dev -n
    - app/console ass:install
    - app/console ass:dump -e=dev
  tags:
    - php
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how you're using gitlab runner to deploy? What do you currently have in your gitlab-ci.yml?

Comment: @Matthew added contents of my `gitlab-ci.yml`

Comment: Thanks. It's still not obvious what's doing the actual docker stuff - is it in the `app/console doc:sch:up` step? Is this your script? what does it do?

Comment: Actually, it's deployment script for apache/php application. It's creating all stuff that need to be configured, then I'm just relying on apache, which is in set and ran in docker image

Comment: Aha - so basically the last part of that script runs forever? Or at least until something stops it?

Comment: you cant use CI for running deployment containers in that way!

Comment: @mohamnag It seems that you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing two concepts: Continuous integration tasks, and docker deployment.

What you have configured is a continuous integration task. The idea is that these perform build steps and complete. Gitlab-ci will record the results of each build step and present it back to you. These can be docker jobs themselves, though they don't have to be.

What you want to do is deploy to docker. That is to say you want to start a docker job that contains your program. Going through this is probably beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer, but I'll try my best to outline what you need to do.

First take what you have a script already, and turn this into a dockerfile. Your dockerfile will need to add all the code in your repo, and then perform the composer / console scripts you list. Use `docker build` to turn this dockerfile into a docker image.

Next (optionally) you can upload the the docker image to a repository.

The final step is to perform a `docker run` command that loads up your image and runs it.

This sounds complicated, but it's really not. I have a ci pipeline that does this. One step runs: `docker build ...` forllowed by `docker push ...` and the next step runs `docker run ...` to spawn the new container.